# Sending inline images using Mailgun and Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, mailgun

I am using Parse.com and Mailgun to send email messages.  I would like to brighten up my emails with images or graphics.  Is there a way to do this using Parse.com CloudCode?

The below reference discusses how to do this.  But, Parse.com method is via CloudCode/Javascript.

[Sending Mailgun Inline Images in HTML using Python Requests library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15299693/sending-mailgun-inline-images-in-html-using-python-requests-library)

[Mailgun user manual](http://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html?highlight=image#sending-inline-images)

Pointers greatly appreciated!