# Inline multiple images Mailgun API Batch

Tags: php, laravel, inline, mailgun

I am trying to pass multiple images via Mailgun's inline API-parameter. I have no problem with only one image, but when I try with multiple images - as in the code below - only the last image in the array is displayed in the email.

```
$template = View::make('emails.template')->render();
$result = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array(
  'from'                =>  $sender,
  'to'                  =>  implode(',',$emailAddresses),
  'subject'             =>  '%recipient.subject%',
  'text'                =>  $messageText,
  'recipient-variables' =>  json_encode($credentials),
  'html'                =>  $template
), array(
  'inline'              =>  array(
    'path/to/image1.png',
    'path/to/image2.png',
    'path/to/image3.png',
    'path/to/image4.png')
));
```

The code above works as if the last element in the array is the only element.

The documentation for sending inline images with Mailgun is found [here](https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#sending-via-api) and it's said [here](https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-sending.html#sending) that "You can post multiple inline values" which means that I'm definitely doing something wrong.

Comment: You're using the official mailgun SDK, right?

Comment: @user866762, yes I am

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was actually a recently introduced bug. A new pull request has been submitted to the official Mailgun PHP SDK, for more info see [here](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php/pull/151).

So to answer the question: the code is working fine, as soon as the SDK is updated according to above pull request. For now I edited my local copy of mailgun-php accordingly and it worked fine. Many thanks to Travis Swientek on Mailgun for quick response.

Comment: Awesome! Good going.

Answer (score 2):

Try this once:

```
$result = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array(
  'from'                =>  $sender,
  'to'                  =>  implode(',',$emailAddresses),
  'subject'             =>  '%recipient.subject%',
  'text'                =>  $messageText,
  'recipient-variables' =>  json_encode($credentials),
  'html'                =>  $template
), array(
  'inline'              =>  array(
    array('path/to/image1.png'),
    array('path/to/image2.png'),
    array('path/to/image3.png'),
    array('path/to/image4.png')
)));
```

Basically wrapping each image path in an array.

Also what is the contents of `$template`?

Comment: when I do that I get following error message: "ErrorException in RestClient.php line 259: Undefined index: remoteName". I also updated my question so you can see what's in $template. Basically it's just my html-code as a string.

Comment: Hmm, yeah this is a tough one without an example of multiple images in the docs. You might need to reach out to them. Check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15302750/1133306). Someone who says they work for Mailgun left an answer (although it's for Python I'm sure the same principle applies) - maybe he can help?

Comment: I contacted him about my question, will keep this post updated if I get any response from outside stackoverflow. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Cool, I'm curious to see what the solution is too.